# Rails: devise_invitable not accepting variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I'm currently trying to show all users that were invited by the current user, but this doesn't work since `@users` is always `nil`.

I'm trying this on `http://localhost:3000/inivtation/new`

My InvitationsController

```
...
    def new
     super
     @users = User.all # This also doesn't work
    end
...
```

My invitations/new.html.erb

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag avatar_url(user) %>
 <%= user.fullname %>
<% end %>
```

The error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: What does `User.all` return on the console?

Comment: why are you calling `super` in your `new` method ?, is the controller inheriting from another one ?. If so, I bet the `new` method from which your controller is inheriting from is returning before your `@users = User.all` code is executed, that's why `@users` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of way to fixing your issue. Please look at my views and choose any of the appropriate one that you feel good.

**Method. 1 ( Simplest )**

Please just use this code and it will work for you simply :)

```rb
<%= User.all.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag avatar_url(user) %>
 <%= user.fullname %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Method. 2 ( Ok but not best )**

Your InvitationsController

```rb
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
 def new   
   @users = User.all
   super
 end
end
```

Your invitations/new.html.erb

```rb
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag avatar_url(user) %>
 <%= user.fullname %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Method. 3 ( Best )**

Your InvitationsController

```rb
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    @users = User.all
    render :new
  end
end
```

Your invitations/new.html.erb

```rb
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= image_tag avatar_url(user) %>
 <%= user.fullname %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Overriding Devise Routes for Method. 2 and Method. 3**

Please make sure about overriding the default invitations controller in your routes :)

```rb
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  invitations: "invitations"
}
```